# simple method that checks text is email with regular expression

Tags: javascript, validation

Can't believe how difficult this seems to be all I want to is to validate a user inout using javascript to make sure that it is an email address. But can't get it to work:

I am using:

```
//validates a regulaer expression
Utilities2.prototype.validateEmail = function(stringToValidateArg)
{

    alert('about to check regexp');

    var regExpPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;

    alert(regExpPattern.test(stringToValidateArg));

}
```

But this always returns false, any ideas why is it because of the regular expression?

Comment: Why are you putting utility methods in a `prototype`?

Comment: please edit your code, so it's better readable. You can simply mark your javascript code and then click on the 'Code'-button the button with the ones and zeros

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best regular expression for validating email addresses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses)

Comment: It works for me: `/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/.test("a@b.com")`

Comment: im using prototype so I can use it like an object? is this not a good idea?

I made a utilities class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular expression that I'm using is

`/([\w-\.\+]+\@[\w-]+\.+[\w]{2,4})/gi`

Try this one, should be a bit simpler :)

Comment: There are TLDs that are more than four characters long.

Comment: Hi, okay thanks I tested this and yeah it works however now Im having a problem passing through that regex from an html onclick event:

Ive posted up @

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997879/having-problems-passing-a-regular-expression-through-to-a-method

Sorry if these are too simple these questions still learning js...:-)